# OSM get current map perspective

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm wondering how to get my current camera perspective in an OSM map. I want to save my current camera perspective so that when I refresh the map (with mapView.invalidate()), it will go back to where I was before the refresh (zoom level and latitude/longitude). Right now, I'm only going back to a default location, which is not what I want. I've been searching for a while to no avail, any help is appreciated.

I currently have an update() method which, when called, attempts to reset the zoom level:

```
void update(boolean zoomToFit) {
    if(selectedStop != null) {
        new GetBusInfo().execute(selectedStop);
        selectedBus = null;
    }
    busLocnOverlay.removeAllItems();
    mapView.invalidate();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "update - ZOOM_TO_SPAN1: " + ZOOM_TO_SPAN_1);
    if (ZOOM_TO_SPAN_1 != 0 && ZOOM_TO_SPAN_2 != 0) 
        mapView.getController().zoomToSpan(ZOOM_TO_SPAN_1, ZOOM_TO_SPAN_2);
}
```

It's currently not working, which leads me to think that there's something else responsible for setting the zoom level. ZOOM_TO_SPAN1/2 are set when I plot objects onto the map - the code snippet is quite long so I won't put all of it, but it basically looks like this:

```
private void plotBuses(boolean zoomToFit) {
        // bunch of stuff here
        for (GeoPoint p : points) { 
            int lat = p.getLatitudeE6(); 
            int lon = p.getLongitudeE6(); 
            maxLat = Math.max(lat, maxLat); 
            minLat = Math.min(lat, minLat); 
            maxLon = Math.max(lon, maxLon); 
            minLon = Math.min(lon, minLon); 
        }
        mapController.zoomToSpan(Math.abs(maxLat - minLat), Math.abs(maxLon - minLon)); 
        mapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint( (maxLat + minLat)/2, (maxLon + minLon)/2 ));
        ZOOM_TO_SPAN_1 = Math.abs(maxLat - minLat);
        ZOOM_TO_SPAN_2 = Math.abs(maxLon - minLon);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should provide a small code snipnet to help others understand your question so they can provide you an answer.

Comment: @laconbass you're right, I totally forgot haha

Comment: looks ways better :D wellcome to SO